# Windows API doesn't work in GetStdHandle()

Tags: c, winapi

I renew my code, but the cursor was still visible. Help me, Thanks. (I am a newbie in C and WinAPI)

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include<windows.h>

int main() 
{
 //Get a STD OUTPUT handle
 HWND StdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

 //Set cursor invisible
 CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CURSOR;
 CURSOR.bVisible = FALSE;
 SetConsoleCursorInfo(StdHandle, &CURSOR);
 system ("pause>nul");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set *all* of the members, add CURSOR.dwSize = 1;  And **never** skip error checking, SetConsoleCursorInfo() returns a BOOL.  At least assert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise the `dwSize` member of `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO`:

```
CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO CURSOR;
CURSOR.dwSize = 1;
CURSOR.bVisible = FALSE;
```

From the docs for [SetConsoleCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The dwSize member of the CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO structure specifies the
>   percentage of a character cell that is filled by the cursor. If this
>   member is less than 1 or greater than 100, SetConsoleCursorInfo fails.

Note also from the same page

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. 
> If
>   the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

Checking the return value would have helped you figure out what was going wrong.